# CMT Transactions (REDUX)

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

Have to bother you again ... (see: [CMT Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462342/cmt-transactions)) Presumed the following:

[image]

All TransactionAttributes set per default to REQUIRED

Question: Why is the find method able to retrieve foo even if the previous commit should not  have been happened? It happened indeed that on invocation of find() Foo is inserted and selected, but why? The transaction has not come to an end at this point as Bar still is to be stored.

Now the following had happened (Bang = DuplicateKeyException):

[image]

Question: **Why Foo is saved?** I thought the method invocation of save(Foo foo) will become a part of the GlobalService transaction as annotated to REQUIRED

OK, maybe the GlobalClient is of interest:

```
public void createFooBar(Foo foo, Bar bar) throws WrappedThingsGoneBadException
{
    try
    {
        fooService.create(foo); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    fooService.doSomethingSilly();

    try
    {
        foo = fooService.findByName(foo.getName());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        barService.create(bar);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The save methods of Foo- and BarService:

```
public Foo create(Foo foo)
{
    em.persist(foo);

    return foo;
}
```

Clarifications highly welcomed!

Comment: Did you see the saved Foo in your database?

Comment: "em" is a javax.persistence.EntityManager, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following happened:

1. You saved the Foo into the database successfully without committing it.
2. The same database user read the uncommitted data. So find succeeded.
3. Bang rolled back the saved Foo in the database.

So the other database users never saw the saved Foo record. Your database user saw it until the rollback happened.

Comment: Thx but Foo is persisted ... stored in the database. That really drives me crazy; 'em' is the EntityManager, injected with @PersistenceContext.

Comment: Are you sure that you use required everywhere, and not requires_new?

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure ... because the next example uses REQUIRES_NEW and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Bug in JBoss 7.1.1: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4552 ...